# Wifi analyser with Pi3

Tags: wifi

i want to know if its possible to set up a Pi3 in such a manner to connect to a report on the wifi signal of certain area.

we install wifi , and want to leave a device in a congested area to establish why in certain times of the the wifi signal is zero and at other times super.

i want to see reports over time for the wifi' networks in a area to determine if there is interference etc

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at using [Wavemon](https://github.com/uoaerg/wavemon) to get some details stats on your WiFi. This article is quite helpful:

http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/10/how-to-use-wavemon-to-monitor-your-wifi-connection/

If you wanted a report, I would possibly look at setting up a cron job to write out to a log file every minute / 5 minutes etc.